# Conflict resolution in documentdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In a distributed fault tolerant system conflict resolution is vital as multiple copies of same date will be mirrored and any request can go to any node concurrently while writing.

I used Riak and Cassandra before. Riak works based on vector clock and we can decide the conflict resolution whether the system will do it automatically or the user have to handle it, generally in case of sensitive date user don't want the system to decide which once to keep and which one to discard. Same goes with Cassandra and it's based on time stamp.

So as per cosomosdb is considered, we have various consistency level starting from Strong to Eventual. Based on the choice of consistency the system might generate sibling.

Q1. So my first question is how the sibling handling and hence conflict resolution is happening.Is there a way to handle the sibling from user side programmatically instead of system decide which one to keep and which one to discard in case of sibling.

Q2. And second question is like vector clock and time-stamp in Riak and Cassandra what is the mechanism in documentdb.

Comment: The old answers are outdated now as cosmos introduced multi-master so conflict resolution is unavoidable. There are two approach either you can let cosmos handle it internally by time stamp or write your own stored procedure to handle it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/conflict-resolution-policies

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-conflicts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cosmos DB employs single master write for a partition key range. Irrespective of the consistency level the writes are guaranteed to be conflict-free. The only time the possibility of conflict is during automatic failover of write region. This scenario is explained in greater detail here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/regional-failover.

In the case of write region failover, any unreplicated writes will be registered as conflicts. Applications can perform a manual merge of this record. Here are the details of ConflictFeedAsync https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readconflictfeedasync.aspx

Comment: The one thing that I would add is that CosmoDB does optimistic concurrency with eTags. Every update should include the eTag from the last  read and fail if the eTag doesn't match meaning that it was updated again between your read and your update.

Comment: On that note, if you want to implement optimistic concurrency with eTags, here is an [extension](https://github.com/ealsur/concurrentdocdb) that might come in handy if you work on .Net (Full framework or Core)

Comment: Is there any link that describes CosmosDB's single master writes and related topic?

Answer (score 0):

@Karthik is right until Cosmos was in single master but with the introduction of multi master(there are chances of concurrent multi region writes) conflict is inevitable.

Either let azure handle conflicts(**LWW**, based on timestamp) which is default if you didn't specify any policy or you write your custom logic to hand it based on your application needs(**Custom**).

For LWW you don't have to do anything but for Custom, once you [specify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-conflicts#create-a-last-writer-wins-conflict-resolution-policy) the policy you can read conflicts and resolve based on your business logic. PFB the java snippet on how to resolve conflicts.

Java Async API

```
FeedResponse<Conflict> response = client.readConflicts(this.manualCollectionUri, null).first().toBlocking().single();
for (Conflict conflict : response.getResults()) {
/* Do something with conflict */
}
```

Java Sync API

```
Iterator<Conflict> conflictsIterator = client.readConflicts(this.collectionLink, null).getQueryIterator();
while (conflictsIterator.hasNext()) {
Conflict conflict = conflictsIterator.next();
/* Do something with conflict */
}
```

Reference: [Manage conflict resolution polices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-conflicts#read-from-conflict-feed)